# Wrong quality claimed by YouTube

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I embedded a YT video in a web page using [this library](https://henrygd.me/bigpicture/). When I play the video for the first time (after having cleaned the browser cache), the video by default is played at a very low quality (I guess it's 360p or 480p) but the YT player says it's 720p60. It's obviously not, in fact when I manually select 720p60 the video starts playing in (real) 720p60.

The problem is not the default 360p (I know it can happen and depends on many factors) but the fact the player claims it's 720p, which can be confusing for the users.

I can see the problem on MacOS with both Safari and Chrome.

Is this a known bug?

Thanks.

Comment: have you got dimensions of embedded player set to around that size or is it the default size?

Comment: Because there isn't any tag for this library, if I were you, I would have first opened an issue on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/henrygd/bigpicture/issues) (because they are far more aware of what you are precisely talking about) and then if there isn't any answer after a while, then coming to StackOverflow.

Comment: @WillBrobin I haven't specified any size, I would say the video preview is constrained by the size of the container but when you click on the play button it automatically opens at almost full screen (that's why I used such library)

Comment: @BenjaminLoison you are right, but the issue seemed to me more dependent on YT because the quality claimed is on the YT player, that's why I asked here. I have just tried to embed the video using the standard YT code and in this case it starts at 360p but it also correctly claims 360p.

Comment: @Eugenio I don't think its anything to do with the YT player as I've never heard that, does it happen if you use a different library or just plain embedded? sounds like a issue with the library, I would open a issue on git